# Does an accurate visualization of floating-point 3-space exist?

Tags: floating-point, visualization, data-visualization

The closest thing I can find is the figure in [this](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/1965/visualizing_floats.php) Gamasutra article. I'm wondering specifically if there are other, more extensive/accurate, visualizations of 32 bit floating-point 3-space?

Comment: Do you mean like the cubic steps figure? Do you want to see the changing resolution over space?

Comment: Right, maybe like a video or interactive application where you zoom around to different locations and you can see how things change.

Answer (score 1):

There are 79228162514264337593543950336 32-bit triples.  That's a lot of points to visualize.

Why don't we start with something much simpler: a visualization of 4-bit floating-point two-space.  4-bit floating point is a strange beast -- the representable values are as follows:

```
encoding    value         encoding    value
    0000    0.0               1000    -0.0
    0001    0.5               1001    -0.5
    0010    1.0               1010    -1.0
    0011    1.5               1011    -1.5
    0100    2.0               1100    -2.0
    0101    3.0               1101    -3.0
    0110    inf               1110    -inf
    0111    nan               1111    nan
```

despite being somewhat strange, it has all the essential characteristics of "regular" floating-point numbers, and so it serves our needs:

```
 inf +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
 3.0 +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
     |
     |
 2.0 +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
     |          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
 1.0 +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
     |          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
 0.0 +          =       =   =   =   =   *   =   =   =   =       =          =
     |
     |          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
-1.0 +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
     |          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     | 
-2.0 +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     |
     |
     |
-3.0 +          +       +   +   +   +   =   +   +   +   +       +          +
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
-inf +..........+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+..........+
   -inf       -3.0    -2.0    -1.0     0.0     1.0     2.0     3.0        inf
```

(Points marked by '+' are representable floating-point numbers; points marked by '=' are doubly-covered representations, and `(0,0)` is quadruply-covered).

There are two features that should jump out: the space has some rotational and reflective symmetries, and the density of the points increases as you get closer to the origin.

(to be continued...)